# Get alpha numeric count from a string

Tags: strings, vb.net

Following is the code I am using to find a separate count for alphabets and numeric characters in a given alphanumeric string:

```
   Public Sub alphaNumeric(ByVal input As String)
        'alphaNumeric("asd23fdg4556g67gh678zxc3xxx")
        'input.Count(Char.IsLetterOrDigit)
        Dim alphaCount As Integer = 0 '<-- initialize alphabet counter
        Dim numericCount As Integer = 0 '<-- initialize numeric counter
        For Each c As Char In input '<-- iterate through each character in the input
            If IsNumeric(c) = True Then numericCount += 1 '<--- check whether c is numeric? if then increment nunericCounter
            If Char.IsLetter(c) = True Then alphaCount += 1 '<--- check whether c is letter? if then increment alphaCount
        Next
        MsgBox("Number of alphabets : " & alphaCount) '<-- display the result
        MsgBox("Number of numerics : " & numericCount)
    End Sub
```

Everything works fine for me. Let me know how I can make this simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general your code looks good, here are a few smaller remarks.

**Method name:**

Capitalize the name of your method and make it more meaningful. Use `CountAlphaNumeric` or something similar.

**Comments in code:**

You can omit the comments in your code. It speaks for itself what the code is doing, certainly because you use clear names for your variables.

**IsNumeric() - Char.IsDigit():**

In the .NET framework, there's the [**`Char.IsDigit`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58(v=vs.110).aspx) method, use this one instead:

```
If Char.IsDigit(c) = True Then numericCount += 1
```

**MsgBox() - MessageBox.Show():**

Although `MsgBox` is valid, it also comes from the VB era. In the .NET framework there's the [**`MessageBox.Show`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) method, use that one instead:

```
MessageBox.Show("Number of alphabets : " & alphaCount)
```

**String.Format():**

To insert variables in a string, use the [**`String.Format`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of just concatenating the values:

```
Dim result As String = String.Format("Number of alphabets : {0}", alphaCount)
```

**"Expression = True":**

You can leave out the `= True` part in your if conditions, since the methods return a boolean value.

This is what the code now looks like:

```
Public Sub CountAlphaNumeric(ByVal input As String)

    Dim alphaCount As Integer = 0
    Dim numericCount As Integer = 0

    For Each c As Char In input
        If Char.IsDigit(c) Then numericCount += 1
        If Char.IsLetter(c) Then alphaCount += 1
    Next

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Number of alphabets : {0}", alphaCount))
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Number of numerics : {0}", numericCount)

End Sub
```

**Using LinQ:**

Although not always the best option, you can achieve the same result using LinQ, using the [**`Enumerable.Count`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) method:

```
Dim alphaCount = input.Count(Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c))
Dim numericCount = input.Count(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))
```

Here's the complete code using LinQ:

```
Public Sub CountAlphaNumericUsingLinQ(ByVal input As String)

    Dim alphaCount = input.Count(Function(c) Char.IsLetter(c))
    Dim numericCount = input.Count(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Number of alphabets : {0}", alphaCount))
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Number of numerics : {0}", numericCount))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Comments should describe **why** something is done, **what** is done should be described by the code itself by using meaningful names for variables and methods.

Speaking of methods, what would `alphaNumeric()` mean to somebody else ? Nothing.

---

Instead of `IsNumeric()` you should nowadays use `Char.IsDigit()`.  This also applies to `MsgBox()` -> `MessageBox.Show()`.

---

The `Char.IsLetter()` and `Char.IsDigit()` (or `IsNumeric()`) methods will return a boolean stating the evaluation. You don't need to compare the result like `If Char.IsLetter(c) = True then` you can simplify this to `If Char.IsLetter(c) then`

---

If the current char is a number, you don't need to check if it is a letter. So you should better use a `if..else if`.

```
If Char.IsNumber(c) = True Then
    numericCount += 1
ElseIf Char.IsLetter(c) Then
    alphaCount += 1
End If
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the guidelines, this is what am actually excepting. thanks a lot